# Laravel message system wuery all tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm creating message system in Laravel4 and I'm so confused how to retrive data from mysql in this way.

For noy a have 3 tables in DB:

```
conversations:
    id                int        A_I PRIMARY
    subject           varchar    128
    created_at        datetime
    updated_at        datetime

conversations_messages:
    id                int        A_I PRIMARY
    conversation_id   int
    user_id           int
    message           text
    created_at        datetime
    updated_at        datetime

conversations_members:
    conversation_id   int
    user_id           int
    last_view         int
    deleted           int
    created_at        datetime
    updated_at        datetime
```

In models:

Conversation.php

```
<?php
class Conversation extends Eloquent {
protected $table = 'conversations';

public function messages(){
    return $this->hasMany('ConversationMessage', 'conversation_id');
}
public function members(){
    return $this->hasMany('ConversationMember','conversation_id');
}   
}
?>
```

ConversationMessage.php

```
<?php

class ConversationMessage extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'conversations_messages';

public function conversation(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Conversation','conversation_id');
}
public function sender(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User','user_id');
}
}

?>
```

ConversationMember.php

```
<?php

class ConversationMembers extends Eloquent {
protected $table = 'conversations_members';

public function conversation(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Conversation','conversation_id');
}
public function member(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User','user_id');
}
}

?>
```

So now In my controller I need to pass conversation variable to view so I can loop thorugh and display messages that belongs to logged in user.

How can I query this:

```
SELECT
"conversations"."id",
"conversations"."subject",
MAX("conversations_messages"."created_at") AS "last_reply"
FROM "conversations"
LEFT JOIN "conversations_messages" ON "conversation"."id" = "conversations_messages"."conversation_id"
INNER JOIN "conversations_members" ON "conversations"."id" = "conversations_members"."conversation_id"
WHERE "conversations_members" = {Auth::user()->id}
AND "conversations_members"."deleted" = 0
GROPU BY "conversations"."id"
ORDER BY "last_reply" DESC
```

How in the world should I do this in my controller? Or if there is a better way please help.

```
return View::make('messages.inbox')->with('conversation', ??????);
```

For now I am trying to do with query builder but don't know how.

```
$con    = DB::table('conversations')
            ->select('id','subject')
            ->max('conversations_messages.created_at')->as('last_reply')
            ->from('conversations')
            ->leftJoin('conversations_messages',function($leftJoin){
                $leftJoin->on('conversations.id','=','conversations_messages.conversation_id');
            })
            ->join('conversations_members', function($join){
                $join->on('conversations.id','=','conversations_members.conversation_id');
            })
            ->where('conversations_members','=',Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('conversations_members.deleted','=',0)
            ->groupBy('cpnversation.id')
            ->orderBy('last_reply','dsc');
```

Comment: so you want all conversations where user is a part of ?

Comment: Yes, I;m trying to do with query builder but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I pulled the code I supplied because it looks like you need to work out the issues with your database structure and your SQL queries before you move forward.

Your SQL query is excluding deleted Conversation Members, not Conversation Messages. If you want to be able to exclude deleted messages, you should have a field on the Conversation Messages table that denotes a deleted message.

Also, I think you can do without the Conversation Member table entirely.  You already store that user id on the message, so you already know who is taking part in conversations.  Another table would be unnecessary here.

Comment: Dtat deleted field means that message is deleted if user deletes the message I don't want to show him that message.

Comment: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given ERROR!

Comment: I am following this guz in order to make it work but how to do it in Laravel? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f30PqxHVJ-I